# How to add points to a single line amongst many lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
  
gfg_data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                   y1 = c(1.1, 2.4, 3.5, 4.1, 5.9, 6.7, 
                          7.1, 8.3, 9.4, 10.0),
                   y2 = c(7, 5, 1, 7, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 4),
                   y3 = c(5, 6, 4, 5, 1, 8, 7, 4, 5, 4),
                   y4 = c(1, 4, 8, 9, 6, 1, 1, 8, 9, 1),
                   y5 = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10))
  
gfg_plot <- ggplot(gfg_data, aes(x)) +  
    geom_line(aes(y = y1), color = "black") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y3), color = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y4), color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y5), color = "purple")
```

I would like to add points to the red line, but simply adding geom_point() after it does not seem to work. Is there any workaround?

Comment: `geom_line(data=data.frame(x=11:13, y=-(1:3)), aes(x, y), color = "red")` (that is, use `data=` on a new frame and handle aesthetics appropriately).

Comment: FYI, it is often better to reshape your data and make just one call to `geom_line` (replacing your five calls there), perhaps `gfg_data %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-x) %>% ggplot(aes(x, value)) + geom_line(aes(group = name, color = name))`